# Covariance with ICollection in C#

Tags: c#

Not the greatest title but there has to be a better way to accomplish what I want. Perhaps the answer is that I want the wrong thing though...

So I have an object with the following structure:

```
public class Viper
{
   public ObservableCollection<Personnel> PersonnelList {get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<Equipment> EquipmentList {get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<Fluid> FluidList {get;set;}
   public ObservableCollection<Event> EventList {get;set;}
}
```

During the running of my app I will receive data packets that contains an object with the same structure as above and I need to merge the properties of these two objects together. There is a specific set of rules on how each item of the incoming collection is added to the base object as follows in the following function:

```
private void ProcessEventCollection<T>(T existing, IEnumerable<IViperEvent> newlist)
    {
        if (newlist == null) { return; }

        var a = existing.GetType();
        var b = newlist.GetType();
        if (a.GetGenericArguments().Single() != b.GetGenericArguments().Single()) { return; }

        var oldlist = (ICollection<IViperEvent>)existing;

        foreach (var evt in newlist)
        {
            switch (evt.Action.ToUpper())
            {
                case "A":
                    oldlist.Add(evt);
                    break;
                case "M":
                    var item = oldlist.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Index == evt.Index);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        oldlist.Remove(item);
                    }
                    oldlist.Add(evt);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    var itemToDelete = oldlist.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Index == evt.Index);
                    oldlist.Remove(itemToDelete);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

All the collection items implement the IViperEvent interface which ensures that there is an Action property and and Index property. Both collections will contain items of the same type. The logic for merging each of the different collections is exactly the same however, I cannot cast ObservableCollection to ICollection for example. I understand why this is not allowed but is there any way I can use this function for all collections that implement the IViperEvent interface? There has to be a way. I just hate copying and pasting this same function with a single line change for PersonnelList, FluidList, EquipmentList, etc.

Comment: Why can't you cast ObservableCollection to an ICollection? It implements the interface...

Comment: @Daniel you can't cast an `ICollection<string>` to an `ICollection<object>`.  For the same reason, he can't do the cast he was trying.

Comment: You can cast to ICollection that is not generic. You try to use ICollection from System.Collections.Generic namespace, but I'm talking about System.Collections.ICollection which does not have generic param. Works with everything.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be a valid option, though the OP's wording implied it was not.  However, `ICollection<T>` (my solution) is, in this case, a better option.  Still, good to know all of the possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
private void ProcessEventCollection<T>(ICollection<T> existing, IEnumerable<T> newlist)
    where T : IViperEvent
```

Comment: Wow...I even had a variant of that in place at one point. Missed it by 10 characters...

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way I can use this function for all collections that
>   implement the IViperEvent interface?

Of course:

```
private void ProcessEventCollection<T>(ICollection<T> existing, IEnumerable<IViperEvent> newlist)
    where T: IViperEvent 
{
    // ...
}
```